# Uppercase filter not working inside angular translate

Tags: html, angularjs, translation, uppercase

I'm trying to display the text of a button in upper-case . There is localisation involved, so the button text will be fetched from the corresponding language files. Language switching works fine , however the upper-case conversion doesn't . If the value of BTN_EDIT is a lower-case text in language file , the text is always shown in lower-case .

```
 <button ng-click="editUserLoginCreditDetails()" ng-show="editLoginCredentialButton" translate="{{'BTN_EDIT'|uppercase}}"></button>
```

Answer (score 8):

The translate directive apparently doesn't allow a filter in that way. Try this:

```
<button ng-click="editUserLoginCreditDetails()" ng-show="editLoginCredentialButton">{{'BTN_EDIT' | translate | uppercase}}</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

I know it is too much late, just in case anyone who face this issue. to solve this issue, you have to use css property `style="text-transform:lowercase;"` and this will solve your problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

If you can try the following way:

```
<button ng-click="editUserLoginCreditDetails()" ng-show="editLoginCredentialButton" translate>{{'BTN_EDIT' | uppercase}}</button>
```

I hope this would work. Let me know, if you face any difficulty.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes! Thank you!